# Is there any query in mongodb to find the specific objects from an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find out a specific question from array of objects from my mongodb database schema. The problem is i don't figure out how to write or summerize the query for this particular JSON file.

Here is the mongoose query i wrote.

```
Device.find({ _id: req.params.device_id })
       .select('question.questionID surveyID')
       .then(device => {
         if (device.length == []) {
           errors.nodevice = 'There is no device for this user';
           res.status(404).json(errors);
         }else{

           // res.json(device[0].question.questionID);
           // res.json({ "surveyID" : device[0].surveyID});

           console.log(device[0].question.questionID);

           Survey
                 // .find({"question.id": {$all: device[0].question.questionID} })
                 .find({ "question.id": { "$in": device[0].question.questionID } })
                 .then(question => {
                   if (question.length == []) {
                     errors.question = 'There is no question for this device';
                     res.status(404).json(errors);
                   }else{
                     res.json(question);
                     // res.json({ "surveyID" : device[0].surveyID});
                   }
                 })
                 .catch(err =>
                   res.status(404).json({ error: err })
                 );
```

Here is the json file.

```
{
"user_id": "asd",
"project_id": "asdad",
"project_name": "asdea",
"question": [
 {
   "id": "Q_1554201813282",
   "type": "checkbox",
   "title": "checkbox1",
   "options": {
     "1554201907907": "c1",
     "1554201917922": "c2",
     "1554201920921": "c3"
   }
 },
 {
   "id": "Q_1554201923908",
   "type": "multipleChoice",
   "title": "multiple",
   "choices": {
     "1554201932066": "m1",
     "1554201936866": "m2"
   }
 }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by mongo function `$elemMatch`.
Your query will be like below.

```
Survey.find( { question: { $elemMatch: { id: device[0].question.questionID } } } , function(err, res){

if(err){
  console.log(err);
} else {
  console.log(res);
}

})
```

Comment: It returns an empty array. it's supposed to give a output like that                                        `[
 {
   "id": "Q_1554201813282",
   "type": "checkbox",
   "title": "checkbox1",
   "options": {
     "1554201907907": "c1",
     "1554201917922": "c2",
     "1554201920921": "c3"
   }
 },
 {
   "id": "Q_1554201923908",
   "type": "multipleChoice",
   "title": "multiple",
   "choices": {
     "1554201932066": "m1",
     "1554201936866": "m2"
   }
 }
]`